# Shell script with executable permissions returns "command not found"

Tags: centos6, shell-scripting

I have a shell script file with executable permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   root       1147 Jan 26  2017 my_script
```

**Even running it as root** - **fully qualified** (path/to/file/my_script) I get the following error:

```
-bash: my_script: command not found
```

SELinux is being enforced and the context label is:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0
```

But even attempting to execute with SELinux disabled

```
Current mode:                   permissive
```

does not remedy the error.  This script has executed as expected in the past.

What am I not understanding - why is this exception being encountered?

Reference:
CentOS release 6.9

Comment: It's unclear that you're calling this fully qualified, otherwise bash would print /path/to/my_script instead... Can you expand the context on that line? In which directory is the script located?

Comment: You don't give enough details of what you're doing... Are you running my_script as root or a non-root user? What are the permissions of the directory that has my_script in it and its parents? What is the first line of my_script, does it start with #! and if so what interpreter does it use there?

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger  The first line of the script starts with #!  and has always ran as expected in the past.

Comment: As @FilipeBrandenburger noted, the question text stating that you are running the script by entering a full path doesn't match the error message immediately after it. Please try running your script again and make your post consistent.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger - The error is originating from a line in the script - and that is why it only shows what I wrote.  I have commented out that line in the script and it now is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`my_script` is not in your PATH. So you have to provide the path to it when calling it directly.

```
./my_script
```

Comment: That's what I mean when I say fully qualified - I include the FULL PATH in the execution statement  /path/to/file/script.sh.

Comment: Really? You did not actually demonstrate this in your question. What you _did_ show indicates that you _did not_ provide the full path. But you posted a lot of stuff about SELinux that doesn't appear to be relevant. Please edit your question.